# Does pip have autocomplete?

Tags: bash, python, pip, auto-completion

Pip has a long list of commands. Is there any way to use auto-complete by <kbd>Tab</kbd> in console (Bash)?

Comment: nice! i it work for me like charm

Comment: @Melebius that counts as an answer.  Please answer, ping me and I'll come back to upvote!

Comment: yes, this comment is a right answer for me.

Comment: would you please change the accepted answer to https://askubuntu.com/a/1026594/470080 as it is now the correct answer @anonymous2

Comment: @Julius I'm not the poster I simply edited the question; there's nothing I can do.

Comment: sorry, meant @Yurij

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE: Don’t forget to look at [muru’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026594/250300) which may provide a more straightforward solution.**

A `pip` autocompletion plugin for Bash can be found at https://github.com/ekalinin/pip-bash-completion.

You can [download it as a ZIP](https://github.com/ekalinin/pip-bash-completion/archive/master.zip) or simply install using Git:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/ekalinin/pip-bash-completion.git
sudo cp ./pip-bash-completion/pip /etc/bash_completion.d/
. /etc/bash_completion.d/pip  # to enable in the current shell, next time should load automatically
```

Comment: do you mind removing this answer as https://askubuntu.com/a/1026594/470080 is the correct answer now

Comment: @Julius Thanks for your reaction but at least 5 people have found this answer useful according to upvotes, so I don‘t think it’s necessary to completely remove it. I’ve added a link to the muru’s answer you mentioned. It’s up to the OP ([Yurij](https://askubuntu.com/users/722922/yurij)) to update which answer he accepted.

Comment: it was useful when it came out, it's not anymore. Are you so attached to your points

Comment: @Julius Even though pip provides a native solution, this answer is still relevant and there is NO good reason to suggest the author to remove it.

Comment: the reason is that it's not useful anymore, and it's still accepted, confusing people. At some point this will be all of code-oriented StackExchange, a million of accepted and upvoted answers that have been erroneous for years. Tell me how that is useful to anyone.

Answer (score 48):

A reasonably current `pip` comes with [built-in functionality](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#command-completion) to create completion helpers for bash, zsh or fish:

```
$ pip help completion

Usage:   pip completion [options]

Description:
  A helper command to be used for command completion.

Completion Options:
  -b, --bash                  Emit completion code for bash
  -z, --zsh                   Emit completion code for zsh
  -f, --fish                  Emit completion code for fish
```

You can use it like so:

```
pip completion --bash >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then start a new shell or `source ~/.bashrc` to have it take effect.

Or to have it load on demand rather than in every shell, do:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/
pip completion --bash > ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/pip
```

and `source` that. This has the advantage of being able to run the same command again at any time to update it, rather than having to edit your main `.bashrc`.

Comment: For the moment the problem is solved with help of @Melebius. I would try your solution too, thanks.

Comment: Funny that the completion does not install automatically together with `pip` if the code is contained in it…

Comment: @Melebius there's no good way for it to do so - packages can't touch files in the user home directories, and installing globally to `/etc/bash.bashrc` is tricky to do automatically

Comment: @muru As you can see in my answer and the linked page, there is also the directory `/etc/bash_completion.d/` where it could be placed more easily.

Comment: @Melebius which is from the bash-completion package, and those are two rather independent packages. This built-in completion code doesn't depend at all on bash-completion, so why would it use that directory?

Comment: @Yurij I checked it works. Also I think this should be the accepted answer since it is built-in in pip and doesn't require downloading git repository.

Comment: To try it out, or add it to your current shell without reloading your whole bashrc, use `. <(pip completion --bash)`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complete [muru’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026594/250300) answer.
I like to keep my `.bashrc` relatively clean, plus if you use the following code, you won't have to update your `.bashrc` if/when the completion snippet has an update!

Just add this single line to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
eval "$(pip completion --bash)"
```

Also, you might want to add that line too, because the completion is only added to `pip`, not `pip3`:

```bsh
complete -o default -F _pip_completion pip3
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Running the command each time a new terminal is open is actually slow. It takes from 1 to 5 seconds on my PC. I used [muru’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026594/250300) at the end.